# Why doesn't IntelliJ properly format this block of code?

Tags: intellij-idea

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.
                out
                .
                        println
                                ("Hello world"

                                )
        ;

    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I press `Ctrl+Alt+L`. I expect that it should format it to something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: My IntelliJ cannot even move a single chained method call to the line above it.

Comment: Regarding chained methods - it can be enabled to align them in Editor->Code Style->Java->... Align when multiline - not only for method calls, but laso method parameters, array initializers etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code is already formatted according to the default style. If you want it formatted differently, change the configuration.